# How to validate excel file with multipart using rest assured

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I have uploaded excel file with post api url using below code.
Now i want to validate excel data.

I have no idea how to achieve this, can some one please help me with sample code?

```
Response response =
    given()
        .headers("build-version", "1.0.0")
        .contentType("multipart/form-data")
        .multiPart("file", new File("filepath"))
    .when()
        .post(prop.getProperty("url"))
    .then()
        .assertThat()
        .statusCode(200)
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
    .extract().response();
```

Comment: Response response = given()
    .headers("build-version", "1.0.0")
    .contentType("multipart/form-data")
    .multiPart("file", new File("filepath"))
    .when()
    .post(prop.getProperty("url"))
    .then()
    .assertThat()
    .statusCode(200)
    .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .extract().response();

Comment: Please edit your post and paste your code in it, not in the comments

Comment: @SiongThyeGoh When you edit a post, please be sure you edit it correctly. Don't paste in the "New contributor" banner with the code from the comment.